# Proving if $x(t)=x_0 $ a constant then $x_0\in\ker(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Show that the Cauchy problem:
>
> \begin{cases}
> \dot{x}=A(x)\\
> x(t_0)=x_0\end{cases}
>
> where $A\in L(E,E)$ has a unique solution that is the curve $x:\mathbb{R}\to E$ given by $x(t)=\exp(tA).x_0$; conclude that the solution curve $x(t)=x_0$ is constant if and only if $x_0\in \operatorname{Ker}(A)$.
>
> **Note**: $L(E,E)$ is the space of linear transformations where $E$ is a Banach space and $A$ denotes a matrix.

Solving the equation:

$$\dot{x}=Ax(t)\implies ln(x(t))=At+c\implies x(t)=k\exp(At) \text{ where $k=e^c.$}$$

Now proving the solution above is unique I used Picard theorem.

To apply Picard theorem it is required to prove that $A$ is Lipschitz continuous:

If I have $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ as two possible solutions:

$$\|A({\varphi}_1-A\varphi_2)\|\leqslant \|A\| \|\varphi_1-\varphi_2\|$$
So taking $L=\|A\|$ we have the Lipschitz constant. Hence applying Piccard's theorem there is only one unique solution.

As we have only one solution:

$$\varphi:\mathbb{R}\times E\to E \text{ given by $\varphi(t,x)=k\exp(tA)$}$$

then $\varphi(x,t)=x(t)\implies k\exp(t_0 A)=x(t_0)\implies k\exp(t_0 A)=x_0$ as $t_0=0$ then $k=x_0$ hence $\varphi_(t,x)=k\exp(At)=x_0\exp(At)$.

Regarding second part, I am not understanding: if $x_0\in \operatorname{Ker}(A)$ and at the same time $x_0$ is constant. How can $x_0\neq 0$ and belong to $\operatorname{Ker}(A)$ if $A\neq 0$?

**Questions**:

Is my solution right insofar?

How do I prove for $x(t)=x_0$ a constant then $x_0\in \operatorname{Ker}(A)$? How is this possible if  $x_0\neq 0$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general your answer seems quite complete. But you mention that $E$ is a Banach space. Since $A$ is a matrix, I guess $E$ is just $\mathbb{R}^n$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x(t)=x_0$ is a constant solution, then $\dot{x}(t) = 0$. From $\dot{x} = Ax$, it follows that $Ax_0 = 0$. This means, by definition, that $x_0 \in \operatorname{Ker}(A)$.

The converse implication goes similarly: if $x_0 \in \operatorname{Ker}(A)$, then $\dot{x}$ is zero, which means that the constant $x(t)=x_0$ is a solution for the Cauchy problem.

Note that a vector $x_0 \in \operatorname{Ker}(A)$ does not have to be the zero vector. The matrix $A$ can be singular. Simple example: consider 
$$
 A = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & -1 \\
 -1 & 1
 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then the kernel $\operatorname{Ker}(A) = \operatorname{span}\{[1,\; 1]^T\}$ consist not only of the zero vector.